# actionlib ImportError for python

Tags: python, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks, ROS noob here. For some reason I get an ImportError for actionlib with the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cv
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('robot_red')
import rospy
import actionlib
#rest of code...
```

which results in "ImportError: No module named actionlib" in the terminal. If anyone can describe what the problem might be I'll be eternally grateful. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45231/actionlib-importerror-for-python/) by [highencast](https://answers.ros.org/users/3333/highencast/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-10-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-10-06**:
I can just create package and run this code without problems. Does that means something you haven't installed?

**Comment by [highencast](https://answers.ros.org/users/3333/highencast/) on 2012-10-06**:
@sam Thx for the input. I think the files for actionlib itself are already installed under opt/ros/electric/stacks/common/actionlib (assuming those are the files) but python/ros isn't finding them. No idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check your *manifest.xml* file in *robot_red* package whether it contains the dependancy on *actionlib*

```
<package>
....
   <depend package="actionlib" />
...
</package>
```

---

Originally posted by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) with karma: 1821 on 2012-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try this: (notice the ROS version you use)

```
  sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-actionlib
```

---

Originally posted by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) with karma: 2570 on 2012-10-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1